# Why do I need to call getRowSorter().modelStructureChanged() before fireTableRowsInserted()

Tags: java, swing, abstracttablemodel

I have a table which extends AbstractTableModel. When data for it arrives, i delete rows and recreate them again with new data. What i do not understand is why do I have to call the following:

```
getRowSorter().modelStructureChanged();
```

before calling

```
fireTableRowsInserted();
```

If i do not do this, fireTableRowsInserted() throws me the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.setModelToViewFromViewToModel(DefaultRowSorter.java:717)
    at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.rowsInserted0(DefaultRowSorter.java:1046)
    at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.rowsInserted(DefaultRowSorter.java:851)
    at javax.swing.JTable.notifySorter(JTable.java:4258)
    at javax.swing.JTable.sortedTableChanged(JTable.java:4106)
    at javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(JTable.java:4383)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(AbstractTableModel.java:280)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableRowsInserted(AbstractTableModel.java:215)
    at ems.ui.components.BoundTable$BoundTableModel.addRow(BoundTable.java:189)
    at ems.ui.components.BoundTable.loadData(BoundTable.java:315)
    at ems.ui.components.BoundTable.modelChanged(BoundTable.java:333)
    at ems.model.BaseDataModel.notifyPropertyChange(BaseDataModel.java:541)
    at ems.model.BaseDataModel.listLoadedFully(BaseDataModel.java:456)
    at 
    at ems.network.HTTPProtobufPoller$2.run(HTTPProtobufPoller.java:107)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:611)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: this error isn't possible to get if TableModel is based on standard arrays types implementer in the related APIs, no way, no idea without [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Do you also fire the appropriate event after deleting rows ?

Comment: Yes i call fireTableDataChanged()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you recreate the entire table (delete rows and then reinsert them) you need to call atleast 'fireTableDataChanged' (if your lazy and don't want to tell the model exactly what has changed and just want it recalculate everything :-).

'fireTableRowsInserted' must only be used when you append data to the table model (ie. don't delete data from the table model).

Comment: Actually I succeed to achieve what I was looking for by firing fireTableDataChanged after all rows inserted. So i could remove this unnecessary code. I'll accept this answer, but I still remain with question why did i get this exception.

Comment: Because you breached the AbstractTableModel contract. You deleted and inserted rows yet you fired an event indicating rows were only inserted 'fireTableRowsInserted()'. If you want to delete and insert and fire a single event you need at the very least to call 'fireTableRowsUpdated(int firstRow, int lastRow)'. The 'fireTableDataChanged' will always work because that signals the model that all rows are possible changed. The 'modelStructureChanged' will also work because that tells the model even the column definitions might have changed.